# xml parsing not working correctly

Tags: python, xml, iterparse

I have an XML file of the structure as follows

```
<article>
<body>
text1
<collectionlink>
text2
</collectionlink>
text3
</body>
</article>
```

I used iterparser for parsing. But its not printing the data correctly. I am adding code here.

from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse,dump

```
def main():
    fp=open("sam.xml",'r')
    tree_dict = create_dict_tree_elements(fp)

def create_dict_tree_elements(fp):
    depth=0
    for event,node in iterparse(fp, ['start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns']):
        if event=='start-ns' or event=='end-ns':
            continue
        if (event == 'start' and depth == 0):
            print node.text
            depth += 1
            continue        

        if (event == 'start' and depth >0 ):
            print node.text
            depth+=1

        if(event =='end' ):
            depth-=1



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My expected output:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Output am getting

```
text1
text2
```

Comment: What are you getting in the output?

Comment: node in depth 0 article
node in depth greatr 1 body 
text1

node in depth greatr 1 collectionlink 
text2

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of ElementTree node.text is the text between the opening tag and the next tag. The text between the closing tag and the next tag can be found in node.tail.

Comment: how to find parent of node.tail in ElementTree

Comment: @user3715935, as far as I know an Element in ElementTree does not keep a reference to its parent. You should keep the reference explicitly.